# GNOME sushi not working on desktop in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: 19.10, desktop-icons, previews, gnome-sushi

GNOME Sushi works fine within Files app. I can preview files with <kbd>space bar</kbd> within any folders of the Files app. However, pressing <kbd>space bar</kbd> has no effect for the files on desktop. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not miss anything.

In Ubuntu 19.10, icons on the desktop are not anymore provided by the file manager Files (a.k.a. nautilus), but by a separate Gnome Shell extension, "Desktop Icons". Sushi works with Files, but not with the extension.

To preview files that live on the desktop, you can go to the Desktop folder in Files.

Comment: Isn't there any way to use it on desktop also? Or any other app that will do that on desktop and files too?

Comment: Moving out nautilus file manager and replacing it by e.g. nemo file manager, which then can handle the desktop the traditional way. Easier might be to move to another desktop such as cinnamon or xfce that still support desktop icons the old way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [Desktop Icons](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1465/desktop-icons/), try [Desktop Icons NG](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2087/desktop-icons-ng-ding/?c=104403) (fork from Desktop Icons). I am using Arch Linux with gnome 40, and this works like a charm. Not really sure if this works on Ubuntu gnome 3.38 or not.

Someone please test this and add a comment or edit this answer, whether it worked or not.

Comment: I am using Desktop Icons NG on Ubuntu 22.04 and when I hit spacebar on a desktop icon I get a popup asking me to install Nautilus-Sushi.

sudo apt install gnome-sushi

This enables it in Files but doesn't seem to work for the desktop until I disable and re-enable DING.

There we go. Much better thank you.